# React form and feedback transition problem

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx

someone can help me to understand why the transition on feedback message after submit doesnt work?

[snippet code here](https://codefile.io/f/JA2FkmLniO)

I think the problem is not in css or tailwind but in component rendering, if someone can, please help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Move your FeedbackMessage outside of your component**

Each ContactForm re-render triggers FeedBackMessage to create new component constant and new html, which is destroying the previous one, so your transition becomes irrelevant

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const FeedbackMessage = ({ statusMessage, isFeedbackVisible }) => {
    return (
      <p
        className={`transition-all duration-300 bg-gray-100 p-4 mt-10 rounded ${
          isFeedbackVisible ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
        }`}
      >
        {statusMessage}
      </p>  
    );
};

export default function ContactForm() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [feedbackText, setFeedbackText] = useState("");
  const [isFeedbackVisible, setIsFeedbackVisible] = useState(false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    info: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  async function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setIsFeedbackVisible(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://path/api/signup/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      setFeedbackText("Email sent! Check your inbox e start now.");

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to submit the data. Please try again.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setFeedbackText("ops.. error, retry later please.");
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFeedbackVisible) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsFeedbackVisible(false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [isFeedbackVisible]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} class="mt-10">
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-8 max-w-md">
          <div class="relative z-0">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={formData.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
              class="peer block w-full appearance-none border-0 border-b border-gray-500 bg-transparent py-2.5 px-0 text-md text-gray-300 focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
              placeholder=" "
            />
            <label class="absolute top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] -translate-y-6 scale-75 transform text-xl duration-300 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:-translate-y-6 peer-focus:scale-75 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-primary peer-focus:dark:text-primary">
              Your name
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="relative z-0">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              value={formData.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
              class="peer block w-full appearance-none border-0 border-b text-gray-300 border-gray-500 bg-transparent py-2.5 px-0 text-md focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
              placeholder=" "
            />
            <label class="absolute top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] -translate-y-6 scale-75 transform text-xl  duration-300 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:-translate-y-6 peer-focus:scale-75 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-primary peer-focus:dark:text-primary">
              Your email
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="pb-10 relative z-0 col-span-2">
            <textarea
              type="text"
              name="info"
              value={formData.info}
              onChange={handleChange}
              rows="5"
              class="peer block w-full appearance-none border-0 border-b border-gray-500 bg-transparent py-2.5 px-0 text-md text-gray-300 focus:border-primary focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
              placeholder=" "
            ></textarea>
            <label class="absolute top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] -translate-y-6 scale-75 transform text-xl text-gray-500 duration-300 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:-translate-y-6 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:text-primary peer-focus:dark:text-primary">
              Say something about you
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={isLoading}
          class="btn bg-black text-white  hover:bg-primary"
        >
          {isLoading ? "sending..." : "Start a Trial"}
        </button>
      </form>
      <FeedbackMessage isFeedbackVisible={isFeedbackVisible} statusMessage={feedbackText} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know :I
Can u help me to rewrite? i've tried to create an external component but never changed :(

Comment: fixed, in some way.. Ty

Comment: @sedprc I've edited your snippet code, you can check it there

Comment: lol, i've fixed rewriting half code and you simply move out (literally) the FeedbackMessage :)
Thank you very much ;)

Comment: As I said it would be enough :)